# $(document).ready(function() stops working as soon as i assign value to variable ( var userid = ${userid}; )

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl, el

I just want to be able to access variable userid in `document.ready` function. It's accessible in the JSP page but not in jQuery. I am able to print value of `${userid}` on the same JSP page but not in jQuery. I have passed `userid` obj with model and view object to this JSP page. However I am not able to access that object.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var examid = ${userid};

  alert("Hello !");
  //alert(username);
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `${userid}`? Assuming it's a string then you need to wrap it in quotes, otherwise you'll be getting a syntax error thrown in your JS code. For example `var examid = '${userid}';` Open the console to double check this

Comment: thank you , yes it is string.  i will try and let u know.

Comment: thank you very much . it solved the problem. it was string so it had to be wrapped in ' ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of ${userid} is a string then you need to wrap it in quotes, otherwise you'll be getting a syntax error thrown in your JS code.
For example var examid = '${userid}';

– Rory McCrossan Apr 4 at 10:45